# Type Storage Class

Tags: c++, object-oriented, type-safety

So I have designed a "type store" in C++ that can hold a single instance of any subclass of a defined type.

Here is an example of how it would be used:

```cpp
class BaseClass { };
class FirstSubClass : public BaseClass { };
class SecondSubClass : public BaseClass { };

TypeStore<BaseClass> store;

// Each of these returns a pointer to the newly created instance
store.Create<BaseClass>();
store.Create<FirstSubClass>();
store.Create<SecondSubClass>();

// Each of these fails (returning nullptr) as an instance already exists for the type
store.Create<BaseClass>();
store.Create<FirstSubClass>();
store.Create<SecondSubClass>();

// Returns pointers to the instances for each type or nullptr if it is not present
store.Get<BaseClass>();
store.Get<FirstSubClass>();
store>Get<SecondSubClass>();
```

I have designed the class in a way that it handles all memory allocation and deallocation, making it easier to use.

If you are wondering what I would use this for, I am currently developing an Entity Component System that would use this for storing components; there can only be a single instance of each component type per entity.

There is one thing I don't really like about my implementation, and that is how I am forced to write the body of my methods in the header. I know this is required because I have a templated class, and I *could* extract them out into another file to be included by `type_store.h`, however I still feel this is a rather messy solution.

And here is the source:

**identifier.h**

```cpp
#ifndef IDENTIFIER_H
#define IDENTIFIER_H

#include <stddef.h>

typedef size_t Identifier;

#endif
```

**type_identifier.h**

```cpp
#ifndef TYPE_IDENTIFIER_H
#define TYPE_IDENTIFIER_H

class TypeIdentifier {
public:
    template<typename T>
    static Identifier GetIdentifier() {
        static Identifier identifier = nextIdentifier++;

        return identifier;
    }

private:
    static Identifier nextIdentifier;
};

#endif
```

**type_identifier.cpp**

```cpp
#include "type_identifier.h"

Identifier TypeIdentifier::nextIdentifier = 0;
```

**type_store.h**

```
#ifndef TYPE_STORE_H
#define TYPE_STORE_H

#include <map>

template<typename T>
class TypeStore {
public:
    typedef std::map<Identifier, T *> Map;

    typedef typename Map::iterator Iterator;
    typedef typename Map::const_iterator ConstIterator;

    ~TypeStore() {
        for (auto iterator = Begin(); iterator != End(); /* unused */) {
            delete iterator->second;

            store.erase(iterator++);
        }
    }

    template<typename V>
    bool Contains() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, V>::value, "incorrect type for container");

        return store.find(TypeIdentifier::GetIdentifier<T>()) != store.end();
    }

    template<typename V>
    V *Get() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, V>::value, "incorrect type for container");

        if (!Contains<V>()) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        Identifier identifier = TypeIdentifier::GetIdentifier<T>();

        return static_cast<V *>(store.at(identifier));
    }

    template<typename V, typename ...A>
    V *Create(A &&... args) {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, V>::value, "incorrect type for container");

        if (Contains<V>()) {
            return nullptr;
        }

        Identifier identifier = TypeIdentifier::GetIdentifier<T>();
        V *instance = new V(std::forward(args)...);

        if (!store.insert(std::make_pair(identifier, instance)).second){
            delete instance;

            return nullptr;
        }

        return instance;
    }

    template<typename V>
    bool Remove() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<T, V>::value, "incorrect type for container");

        Identifier identifier = TypeIdentifier::GetIdentifier<T>();

        delete Get<V>();

        return store.erase(identifier) == 1;
    }

    typename Map::size_type Size() {
        return store.size();
    }

    Iterator Begin() {
        return store.begin();
    }

    Iterator End() {
        return store.end();
    }

    ConstIterator Begin() const {
        return store.begin();
    }

    ConstIterator End() const {
        return store.end();
    }

    ConstIterator CBegin() const {
        return store.cbegin();
    }

    ConstIterator CEnd() const {
        return store.cend();
    }
private:
    Map store;
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### unique_ptr:

You might consider using at least some automated memory management internally. If the `TypeStore` will retain ownership of all objects it creates, instead of this:

> ```
> typedef std::map<Identifier, T *> Map;
>
> ~TypeStore() {
>     for (auto iterator = Begin(); iterator != End(); /* unused */) {
>         delete iterator->second;
>         store.erase(iterator++);
>     }
> }
> ```

You could simply store a `unique_ptr` in the map and completely remove the `TypeStore` destructor:

```
typedef std::map<Identifier, std::unique_ptr<T>> Map;
```

The `delete`s you have scattered around would also go away. A much cleaner solution, IMO.

#### Use of null as an error indicator:

You chose to return `nullptr` to indicate errors. Unfortunately that precludes returning a reference to the object. A reference would be better because it more clearly conveys the notion that the object is owned by `TypeStore`, so there'd be no risk of accidentally attempting to delete a pointer returned by the store.

You might consider other ways of indicating the errors instead, so you could return references. One might be exceptions, but that's not a great strategy if the `TypeStore` is expected to get invalid requests often. The other strategy which would also be a great fit in this case is an *optional type*. Sadly there's currently no such type in the Standard, but the next best thing is [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

In any case, this is more of a suggestion, if you're comfortable with your current design, by all means, keep it. Just be sure to document clearly that the pointers returned are not to be deleted outside `TypeStore`.